# Remove macros etc from office documents via ruby

Tags: ruby, ms-word, libreoffice, abiword

Is there a way of specifying components to remove from MS or Openoffice documents via ruby? I'm talking about removing macros/meta information and also removing/replacing images. I've looked at a number of conversion programs with a view to doing a conversion from/to the same file format, but I can't find any that allow such options to be specified.

I've looked at:

- [Convert_office](https://github.com/stuzart/convert_office)
- [Abiword](https://github.com/simmogs/abiword) - I've modified the original gem to allow conversion to doc as well as pdf.

Comment: Is JRuby - and thus java components - an option for you?

Comment: @JasonPlutext I'd rather stick to a ruby solution as I don't have jRuby or Java experience but if there's no other alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docx files are really zip files. You can unzip them (inflate) into a directory and delete or change the files you need, and update references to those files. The files inside the zip are text files, XML, so you can use LibXML-Ruby or Nokogiri.

Comment: I was hoping for something that covered older versions of Word as well, but in the absence of a better answer, I'll mark yours as correct. Obviously what I'm looking for doesn't currently exist, publicly at least.